# VBA Split function

Tags: string, vba, excel, split

Input format = `https://instagram.com/baby_blues_tattoos/`
or           = `https://instagram.com/baby_blues_tattoos`

Expected Final Value for variable `usname` =  `followers/baby_blues_tattoos`

Current Final Value for Variable `usname` =  `followers/`

I am not able to extract the username from the input using the code below Need help.

```
Option Explicit
Sub InstaUs()

Dim wk, ws, wc As Worksheet
Set wk = Sheets(3)  'Art
Set ws = Sheets(2)  'Shop
Set wc = Sheets(10) 'Output

Dim str, i, j, l, FinalRowArt, FinalRowShop, FinalRowOut, fol
Dim Cet, usname

fol = "followers/"

FinalRowArt = wk.Range("M900000").End(xlUp).Row
FinalRowShop = ws.Range("L900000").End(xlUp).Row
FinalRowOut = wc.Range("A900000").End(xlUp).Row
j = 2
For i = 2 To FinalRowArt

If wk.Range("M" & i) <> "" Then
str = wk.Range("M" & i).Value
Cet = Split(str, "/")

usname = Cet(UBound(Cet))
usname = fol & usname
wc.Range("A" & j) = usname
j = j + 1

Else: End If
Next i

For i = 2 To FinalRowShop
If ws.Range("L" & i) <> "" Then
str = ws.Range("L" & i).Value
Cet = Split(str, "/")

usname = Cet(UBound(Cet))

usname = fol & usname
wc.Range("A" & j) = usname
j = j + 1

Else: End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `https://instagram.com/baby_blues_tattoos/`... `split` for the last element there is blank?

Comment: So do an `if` statement to test if string ends in `/`? If so, take second to last element of `split`?

Comment: @findwindow I tried using if-else statement to check if last element is blank or not and if it's blank I assigned the second last element to usname but still same result

Comment: Uh don't see that in your code? Post it?

Comment: @findwindow I removed it since it wasn't working

Comment: Um that may be the part you need help with XD

Comment: Just add `if right(str,1)="/" then usname = Cet(UBound(Cet)-1)` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `If` statement once you  establish `str`

```
    If Right(str, 1) = "/" Then
        Cet = Split(Mid(str, 1, Len(str) - 1), "/")
    Else
        Cet = Split(str, "/")
    End If
```

Comment: Still amusing OP tried `if else` but did not post said code XD

Comment: @findwindow & Scott Thank you for your help.